# Bootstrap table does not reaload properly after Bootstrap modal closes

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-table

I have a modal that when the user select an item in a table I must close the modal and update a table that is on a parent page.

This table in a parent view has a column with buttons and when the modal closes and I reaload the table the data-formatter method is not called and the buttons are not displayed.

This is the method that I use to load data in my table:

```
function LoadTableData() {    
    $table = $('#myTable');

    $.ajax({
        url: $url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: { Id: parseInt($('#Id').val()) },
        success: function (data) {
            $table.bootstrapTable('load', data.rows);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Erro ao atualizar a grid");
        }
    });
}

function formatButtons(value, row, index) {
    var editar = '<a class="edit ml10" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Editar"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>';
    var excluir = '<a class="remove ml10" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Excluir"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>';

    return [
        editar, excluir
    ].join('');
}


<table data-toggle="table" id="myTable"
   data-classes="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered"
   data-striped="true"
   data-detail-view="false"
   data-show-columns="false"
   data-click-to-select="true"
   data-id-field="Id"
   data-show-toggle="false"
   data-pagination="false">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th data-field="Title" data-sortable="false" data-align="left">Title</th>
           <th data-formatter="formatButtons" data-align="center"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
 </table>
```

My modal:

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
    type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DEFAULT,
    size: BootstrapDialog.SIZE_WIDE,
    title: 'Parcelamento Customizado',
    message: $('<div id="modalSelecionarClausula"></div>').load(url),
    buttons: [{
        label: 'Voltar',
        action: function (dialogItself) {
            dialogItself.close();
        }
    }, 
    {
        label: 'Selecionar',
        id: "btnSelecionarClausulas",
        cssClass: 'btn-primary',
        action: function (dialogItself) {
            LoadTableData(); //Here I call the refresh table
            dialogItself.close();
        }
    }]
});
```

[image: The table before and after]

Any ideia about how to make it work?

**UPDATE**

Console after modal closed.
[image]

Comment: Can you add console.log(data.rows); to show the data in success function?

Comment: @wenyi post edited. The problem is that the method "formatButtons" is not called when the modal is closed.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle to show your problem? For example like these: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/1765